# User Management - with different levels

Tags: 7, users

We are working on a site building using drupal. We have 3 different user profiles / roles.

1. Site Administrator (manage client admin and content)
2. Client Administrator (manage department admins)
3. Department Administrator (manage his own content)

Project Flow: Site admin, will manage client administrator. Whereas client admin will manage department administrator.

Since we are at the beginner level in Drupal, I wanted to know which module will suit the above user management.

Answer (score 0):

For each role you can grant access control with permissions, so each user with specific role can manage any content or users you want to.

1. [Managing access control with permissions and user roles](http://drupal.org/node/22275)
2. [User: access and management settings](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/user)

Comment: As per the flow, users with specific role will able to edit his content and manage his own departments. For eg. We have CLIENTA and CLIENTB. CLIENTA adds ART DEPARRTMENT AND BIOLOGY DEPARTMENT. Whereas CLIENTB adds PHYSICS DEPARTMENT and DENITISTRY DEPARTMENT. CLIENT A will be able to manage his own content, departments - art and biology users and their content. He can't be able to see the content or users of CLIENT B .